# Reading Unstructured Schema into Spark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have some data that is mostly structured consistently, but there is one particular field that may be one of several different structures, and I'm unsure how to approach this. You can imagine the data comes in like this, where the structure of `col_2` is one of three different types:

```
{"col_1": "a", "col_2": "b"}  # type 1
{"col_1": "b", "col_2": [{"subcol_1": "c"}, {"subcol_1": "d"}]}  # type 2
{"col_1": "c", "col_2": {"subcol_2": "e", "subcol_3": "f"}}  # type 3
```

What's the best approach for reading this into spark, given that it seems to imply `col_2` would be a mixed type? Ideally I'd like to be able to dump this back into JSON after some manipulations, and storing it as a string seems clunky. One benefit is that I am able to correlate `col_1` to the type of `col_2`, i.e. when `col_1` == 'a' then `col_2` is always type 1, etc.

Right now I'm working in Scala, but if this is for some reason doable in Pyspark but not Scala then that's also fine.

Comment: spark is not really designed for flexible schema...

Comment: @mck that seems to be my finding here as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that give your input column with a json string you coud use the function from_json to transform into a **StructType** or **ArrayType(StructType)** column. But, because you have three different formats you have two options:

1. Create a global schema that can represent the three formats. Missing keys will be filled with null. Then you could filter using the **when** function to create three different columns.
2. Using a UDF(or three) to create the desired output.

I think that these are the two main possibilities.

Comment: Multiple global schemas seems a little overkill. I am familiar with UDFs, you provide an example of what you mean for how it'd be applied here?